# Removing duplicate nodes from a sorted linkedlist with a simple code

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to write a method to delete duplicate nodes from a sorted linkedlist. If the method gets the input linkedlist : 1->1->2->2->3->3 it should make the linkedlist like 1->2->3 . but the problem is it returns 1->1->2->3 that means the first duplicate element is not determined ! here is my code :

```
void removeDuplicates(Node head)
{
  Node* Current = &head;
  while(Current != NULL && Current->next != NULL)
  {
    while(Current->next != NULL && Current->next->info == Current->info)
        Current->next = Current->next->next;

    Current=Current->next;
  }
}
```

whole code added : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hstGyDJrkN/

Comment: `the_list.erase(std::unique(the_list.begin(), the_list.end()), the_list.end());` would be the usual solution to "Removing duplicate nodes from a sorted linkedlist". See [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)

Comment: Did you notice that head is a pointer? https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/description/

Comment: by the way, you just "forget" nodes you want to remove from list, you do not delete object, its memory leak

Comment: `std::unique` could work, if the node is passed by reference instead of pointer and is provided with additional increment and comparison operators - and probably assignment, too, preferably move-assignment in given case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you pass head by value, so you create copy of head Node, and change next field of copy, not original head pointer. You should pass pointer by reference, so your signature should look like

```
void removeDuplicates(Node* &head)
```

so you will modify actual head pointer

Comment: Did you test that before posting?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use c++ algorithm

> std::unique

as shown here
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique

You just have to furnish a good

> binary predicate

which returns ​true if the elements should be treated as equal. 
The signature of the predicate function should be equivalent to the following:

```
bool binaryPredicate(const  Node& a, const  Node& b);
```

Comment: `std::unique` will increment the pointer, though, which likely yields a different result than `pointer = pointer->next`; so we need some extra work to get this right...